# How to download files from internet to app internal subdirectory for use in app (android) only without asking permission for storage in Ionic 4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, cordova-plugins

My project requires to save a zip file in app internal directory to unzip it and use the contents in the app. But, it is requiring to ask user for **permission to access photos and videos**, which is scary for some users. Looking for a method where I can save it in any app subdirectory

Appreciate all the help

Comment: What plug-in are you using? I know certain gallery plugins can access files as well but you might want one that's specialized in storage and will only request storage.

Comment: Android won't allow you to store files without asking users for storage permission. What I recommend is that you show a popup telling users why permission is necessary and then request for the storage permissions.